# Is Google Drive suitable for use as a corporate file share?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm not sure that this is a programming question. It would be if there was an API that allowed developers to add and remove users from a drive, for instance.

Is Google Drive only for personal use? Is there a way to make a single drive and share it with a group of users? Is there a way to create a user with read only access?

Comment: I think Google would be happy to see a corporation storing their confidential files on Drive :-)  Do keep in mind that no matter what access controls you can place on cloud-stored files, the company doing the hosting will be able to read/write or remove files at will. Also, should the hosting company decide that giving away storage isn't a good idea, there goes your data.

Comment: Microsoft has full control of most people's hard drives. They are people too: they know that stealing your data on purpose or erasing files at will is bad. So they don't do that on purpose. How is it different for Google or Amazon?

Comment: There are lots of systems where the company doing the hosting has no access to your files. There are encryption schemes that handle this nicely. There are also many, many companies (some with hundreds of employees) that have all data stored on a single non backed up hard drive in a poorly protected office. These computers break down and get stolen all the time. Its pretty likely that files on Google Drive are safer than files on the company bot netted XP service pack 1 machine in the corner.

Comment: I have no doubt there may be some service providers that blindly store files with no processing thereof, but, as the terms of use for Google Drive state, Drive isn't one of them.  Your comparison to a self hosted solution is a bit misleading as a company can (and will) isolate stores of important data from being accessible, by any means, from the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Google Drive web UI shares the same functionalities as the old Google Docs web UI, meaning that you can share documents and folders (collections) to specific set of users or groups with specific access (read-only, read-write, owner).
The [Google Drive API](http://developers.google.com/drive) doesn't let you control the ACL but you can still use the [Documents List API](http://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list) to accomplish that.

Comment: No, it does not.  In important ways, it does not.  Gone is the ability to access folders that have been shared with you.  In a corporate setting, most content is shared with users via shared folders - so this change renders the new UI very unfriendly.  And woe to the user who inadvertently choses to add a large corporate folder ("Projects") to their Google Drive - they will have no clue what just happened.

Comment: The ability to share and access shared folder is still there with some UI tweaks. You might find this [help article](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2375057&p=swm_ww_new) useful.

Answer (score 4):

The Drive sharing model is per-file based and also per-folder based. As Alain stated for now you will have to use the Document List API to control the ACL programmatically, with which you can share entire folders of a Drive account with other people or with groups of people.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements in terms of access control are met.
From that point of view it's quite powerful.

But I agree with @Jan-Z and @daniel-gerson that GDrive has the most cumbersome and unintelligible logic/ui of all file sharing systems, plus the desktop client is buggy.

Users find some of "their" files have disappeared without understanding why, and while there is some  *logic* behind it it's just nobody's logic. You shouldn't have to train your users for this kind of tool in order not to lose work.

Also, the "my drive" folder has a real folder structure behind it, but everywhere else folders are just "tags" and a set of files can have many. Those two logics never correctly make sense together, and you are left wondering where some of those files are, and what happens if you delete them in one place. It's the power of a Ferrari engine on a Vespa Scooter - you'll never make a turn safely.

We are into it, **NOBODY** is liking it and we are just looking out to get out with it with the minimum cost (not product price, but transition cost).

Answer (score 1):

No, I would advise against using Google Drive for a corporate file share. There's a reason it's still in Beta. My Google drive has been syncing 3 small files for the last week, and hasn't been able to complete this simple task.

When it works, it works well, but it's by no means ready for a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, I think Stefano is spot on when he says:

"Also, the "my drive" folder has a real folder structure behind it, but everywhere else folders are just "tags" and a set of files can have many. Those two logics never correctly make sense together, and you are left wondering where some of those files are, and what happens if you delete them in one place."

This is a fundamental difference between the way Google Drive handles files and the way windows explorer handles files.  There is no foolproof way to translate the two directory structures, so if you want to use the Google UI (Web or Desktop) for your corporate file share, I think that is a bust...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I would use google drive (the free version) as a corporate file share.  However, we have been using Drive on Google Apps for Business (the paid version of Google Apps) for some now and we have found it to be a reliable file storage solution.

However, the Google Drive is used only for backend file storage.  File access is controlled through our own software using the Google Drive SDK, and nobody uses or even has access to the file structure through either the Web UI or the Google Drive Desktop application.

I have recently started to use the Google Drive Desktop application to maintain an extra backup copy of our files at each of our office locations, but have not been using it long enough to vouch for it.